# How Many Stable Orbits Could Fit In The Goldilocks Zone?

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, habitability

Scientists aren't really sure of the exact size of the "goldilocks zone" for the sun, where the light said star puts out allows liquid surface water to exist with an atmosphere, but some estimates put it an roughly somewhere between 0.38 to 10.0 AU from the sun (AU is short for "astronomical unit", which uses the distance between the sun and the Earth as a baseline), according to Wikipedia. Assuming that some might be gas giants with moons, roughly how many planetary orbits could fit into this space before they start to get so close that their gravity starts affecting the orbits of the others and/or has negative effects on the plants themselves?